# How do I update value of a ContextVar in an async function?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

It seems that when I reference a `contextlib.ContextVar` in an async function its a copy of the actual. Thus when I update its value it wont be persisted, is there a way to pass the context by reference instead?

```py
import asyncio
from contextvars import ContextVar
import uuid
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

req_context = ContextVar("req_context")

def do_something():
    print("uuid in do something: ", req_context.get())

async def do_something_async():
    req_context.set({
        **req_context.get(),
        "async1": "1",
    })
    print("uuid in do something async: ", req_context.get())

async def do_something_async2():
    req_context.set({
        **req_context.get(),
        "async2": "done",
    })
    print("uuid in do something async2: ", req_context.get())

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    print("=====\n\n0uuid: ", req_context.get({}))
    req_context.set({"REQ_ID": uuid.uuid4()})
    print("1uuid: ", req_context.get())
    do_something()
    await asyncio.gather(
        do_something_async(),
        do_something_async2(),
    )
    print("2uuid: ", req_context.get())
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

When I run

```
0uuid:  {}
1uuid:  {'REQ_ID': UUID('e5efe0a0-5975-43b9-aff3-9e618ffb8be0')}
uuid in do something:  {'REQ_ID': UUID('e5efe0a0-5975-43b9-aff3-9e618ffb8be0')}
uuid in do something async:  {'REQ_ID': UUID('e5efe0a0-5975-43b9-aff3-9e618ffb8be0'), 'async1': '1'}
uuid in do something async2:  {'REQ_ID': UUID('e5efe0a0-5975-43b9-aff3-9e618ffb8be0'), 'async2': 'done'}

# Notice the mutations do not get saved to the original context

2uuid:  {'REQ_ID': UUID('e5efe0a0-5975-43b9-aff3-9e618ffb8be0')}
```

Or perhaps I am using the wrong thing?

Comment: `asycio.gather` wraps coroutines in tasks and each task has its own context.

Comment: Hmm yeah is there a way to get around this? @MichaelButscher or is contextvar not the right way for this?

Comment: @JiewMeng, yes, it's not for your case, the outer contextvar preserves its initial value https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#contextvars.Context.run

Comment: As @RomanPerekhrest says, `ContextVar` is probably not right for your usecase. What are you *actually* trying to do, what problem.are you solving?

Comment: @M.O. I want to be able to pass/set context in various lifecycle of a request eg. web/SQS/Kafka request mainly for the purpose of adding this info in logging for better debugging

Comment: Yes, in that case a `ContextVar` is most likely what you want. You juat have to handle that if you call `asyncio.gather` like this, those get separate contexts. In this case, I would probably just return the values you need from `do_something_async` and `do_something_async2`, and log that in the API route function.